# NextJS PromptCard component throwing a 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'image')' error - what is the cause?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I am trying to render PromptCard component through my PrompCarList component in my NextJs App. But I am getting the error above. I logged the post to the console but it does  not show the user data even I set ref to the 'User' in the models. Please can anyone help me to find the problem ?

this the result of console.log(post) in the PromptCard.jsx file

```
`{_id: '64770098152922e3f36c8414', prompt: 'Test prompt', tag: '#product', __v: 0}
prompt:"Test prompt"
tag:"#product"
__v:0
_id:"64770098152922e3f36c8414"
[[Prototype]]:Object`
```

I am wondering if it is working ref:'User' code

```
//-----This is PromptCard.jsx file

import {useState} from 'react'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react'
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation'

const PromptCard = ({post,handleTagClick,handleEdit,handleDelete}) => {
  console.log(post)
  return (
    <div className='prompt_card'>
      <div className='flex justify-between items-start gap-5'>
        <div className='flex-1 flex justify-start items-center gap-3 cursor-pointer'>
          <Image src={post.creator.image} alt='user_image' width={40} height={40} className='rounded-full object-contain'/>
          <div className='flex flex-col'>
            <h3 className='font-satoshi font-semibold text-gray-900'>{post.creator.username}</h3>
            <p>{post.creator.email}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default PromptCard;

//----------------------

this is Feed.jsx file

import {useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import PromptCard from './PromptCard'

const PromptCardList=({data,handleTagClick})=>{
  console.log(data)
  return (
    <div className='mt-16 prompt_layout'>
      {data.map((post)=>{
        return (
          <PromptCard key={post._id} post={post} handleTagClick={handleTagClick} />
        )
      })}

    </div>
  )
}

const Feed = () => {
  const [allPosts,setAllPosts]=useState([])
  const [searchText,setSearchText]=useState(''); 
  const handleSearchChange=(e)=>{}

  useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchPosts=async()=>{
      const respone= await fetch('/api/prompt')
      const data= await respone.json()
      setAllPosts(data)      
    }
    fetchPosts()
  },[])
  return (
    <section className='feed'>
      <form className='relative w-full flex-center'>
        <input
          type='text'
          placeholder='Search for a tag or a username'
          value={searchText}
          onChange={handleSearchChange}
          required
          className='search_input peer'
        />

      </form>

      <PromptCardList data={allPosts} handleTagClick={()=>{}}/>

    </section>
  )
}

export default Feed;

--------------------MODELS---------------

`import { Schema, model, models } from 'mongoose';

const PromptSchema = new Schema({
  creator: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  },
  prompt: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Prompt is required.'],
  },
  tag: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Tag is required.'],
  }
});

const Prompt = models.Prompt || model('Prompt', PromptSchema);

export default Prompt;


import {Schema,model,models} from 'mongoose'


const UserSchema= new Schema({
    email:{
        type:String,
        unique:[true,'Email already exists'],
        required:[true,'Email is required'],
    },
    username:{
        type:String,
        required:[true,'Username is required'],
        match:[/^(?=.{8,20}$)(?![_.])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._]+(?<![_.])$/, "Username invalid, it should contain 8-20 alphanumeric letters and be unique!"]
    },
    image:{
        type:String,
    }
})

const User=models.User || model('User',UserSchema)
export default User;`
```